# In Highcharts, how to set width of plot bands on y-axis in column chart?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is there a smart way of sizing and aligning plot bands on the y-axis to the x-axis columns? The size seems to use the x-axis' width.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/remisture/hvy162k5/13/

I'm trying to have the plot bands to the left of the column, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/remisture/hvy162k5/12/ - where I basically set the `.chart-column` width small enough to "fake" it, but this varies across browsers, so I need to find a better solution.

The `thickness` property of PlotBand objects doesn't seem to help me either.

```
plotBands: [{
    from: 0,
    to: 2500,
    color: '#FB8585'
  }, {
    from: 2500,
    to: 5500,
    color: '#F9E7AE'
  }, {
    from: 5500,
    to: 8000,
    color: '#83DAD9'
  }]
```

**This is how it is**

[image: This is how it is]

**This is how I like it to be**

[image: This is how I like it to be]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about this using the `xAxis` scaling, `pointRange`, `pointPadding`/ `groupPadding`

Something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    pointRange: 1,
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0
  }
},
xAxis: {
  min: -0.5,
  max: 0,
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  visible: false,
}
```

- Set the `pointRange` to 1 to make the column fill one axis unit's width (this makes everything scale properly);
- Set the `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` to 0 to remove unnecessary space from the column plotting;
- Set the axis `minPadding` and `maxPadding` to 0 to remove unnecessary space from the axis;
- Set the xAxis `min` to less than 0, and the max to 0, to allow space for the bands to show on the left side (to show them on the right instead, set the min to 0, and the max to something greater than 0);

This way, you can set the chart width to whatever you want, and the column/bands should fill appropriately.

- To make the portion of visible bands narrower, set the x axis min to something closer to zero (e.g. `-0.25`) - to make them wider, set the min to something further from zero (e.g. `-0.75`).
- The `xAxis` `min` setting will determine the proportion of the x axis that will be taken up by both the column, and the visible `plotBands`. Adjust accordingly.

**Update Fiddle:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/hvy162k5/16/

**Output:**

[image: screenshot]